# Show Dynamic image data to the img html element - Laravel, Collective

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravelcollective, laravel-views

I am dealing with 2 variables here. 1st being `$xyz` which contains all the values I would like to bind to the form and 2nd being `$fields` which contains all the input fields.

I am looping through `$fields->field_name` to show all the form fields from the database.

But 1 of the fields being an image, which is a different case. I am simply trying to bind manually the image url to the img element here.

To successfully bind an image. I need 2 things, 1 being the field name which I can get it from `$fields->field_name` and second is the url which is in `$xyz`.

so, I plan to do something like: `$xyz->get($fields->field_name)`. **This means, I try to access $xyz object and get dynamic image field name.** but not sure why my below code throws error:

```
<img src=" {{ url($xyz->get($fields->field_name)) }}"  />
```

code like above works completely fine in Controller, not sure how to achieve this in Blade front-end Views.

## error:

**Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::columnize() must be of the type array, string given**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself:

below works, instead of using get:

```
{{ $xyz[$fields->field_name] }}
```